# How to Stop Unwanted repeated variable in twitter-bootstrap dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have multi link to delete via ajax:

```
<a id="id-1">link1</a>
<a id="id-2">link2</a>
<a id="id-3">link2</a>
<a id="id-4">link2</a>
...
```

this is a simplified of my code:

```
$(document).on("click", "[id^=id-]",function(event) { 
        event.preventDefault();
        var btnid = this.id;
        alert('1:'+btnid );

        // a dialog confirm to aks delete  in bootstrap
        $("#confirmbtn").on( "click", function(event) {
            alert('2:'+btnid );
        });
})
```

when I refresh page for first one I got this in alert:
(click on `<a id="id-1">link1</a>`)

```
1:id-1
2:id-2
```

but for second,third and ... I got wrong!

for example for second:
(click on `<a id="id-1">link2</a>`)

```
1:id-2
2:id-1
2:id-2
```

the third:
(click on `<a id="id-1">link3</a>`)

```
1:id-3
2:id-1
2:id-2
2:id-3
```

I expect

```
1:id-3
2:id-3
```

can help me to solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are binding event handler inside another event handler, a new event handler is getting attached every the element is clicked, thus you are getting the issue. You can use [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to persist arbitrary data.

```
$(document).on("click", "[id^=id-]",function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    var btnid = this.id;
    alert('1:'+btnid );

    $("#confirmbtn").data('id', this.id)
})

// a dialog confirm to aks delete  in bootstrap
$(document).on( "click", "#confirmbtn", function(event) {
    alert('2:'+$(this).data('id'));
});
```

Comment: thanks. your answer was great. I do not know that. But the answer for me: only add '$(this).off('click');' in the end of `$(document).on( "click", "#confirmbtn", function(event) {...`

Comment: @anda I don't like that approach hence not suggested that. You can also use `.off().on(`

Answer (score 2):

You are binding multiple eventhandlers to the button. With each clicked link (link-1, link-2 etc.) you add a new one to the button, but the existing ones remain. To solve this, you could add an event handler to the confirm-button on initialization and use a variable, which tells you anytime, which link was clicked last. You could do this like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var lastLinkId;

   $("#confirmbtn").click(function() {
      alert("2: "+lastLinkId);
   });

   $(document).on("click", "[id^=id-]",function(event) { 
      event.preventDefault();
      lastLinkId = this.id;
      alert('1: '+lastLinkId);
   });
});
```

Comment: Sorry @Satpal, didn't saw your answer as I was writing my one.

Comment: It's fine dear. As you have suggested a different approach. No need for apologies